# Java How to use a JButton that created in for loop, outside the loop?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton

My point is how to use a method outside of the for loop. I can't use outside because all button are created for loop. Whenever I create an array button then I give some properties of button's they don't work

```
private clicks = 0;
JButton[] test = new JButton[24];
for(i=0; i < 24; i++){
    test[i] = new JButton("" + i);
    test[i].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    //and some properties ,action listener
    if((clicks < 15) && clicks % 5 !=0 ) {
        test[].setVisible(False);// i don't know what to write in "[]"
    }
    clicks++;
    else if(clicks%5 == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(p1, calculateAverage(anArrayList));
    } //calculate average is a method that i created it
}
   test[].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//i dont know what to write in [] 

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    

                    if((clicks < 15) && clicks % 5 !=0 ) {
            test[].setVisible(False);// i don't know what to write in "[]"

        }
        clicks++;
        else if(clicks%5 == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(p1, calculateAverage(anArrayList));
         } 
     }
```

`calculateAverage` method is always gives the same output. How can I fix this? When I put the `if-else` code is the outside of the loop I cant use the buttons.

Comment: "_I can't use outside because all button are created for loop_" But you created the array outside the loop so you can access that. `test[i]`. Also, please take the time to use your spacebar and correctly indent your code.

Comment: I'm sorry. i was trying to show how i can creat the buttons outside. Normally buttons are created in inside without array

Comment: So it sounds like you answered your own question - if you want to use them outside of your loop make an array just use the code you posted. If there is some clarification you can provide it would be great because I don't know what the issue is here.

Comment: This line `clicks++;` followed by and `else` won't compile...

Comment: i've editted my code plase look again. i still can't get use to this website. i always tried to tell my problem properly but every time i couldn't :)

Comment: *Assume that this code comes right after for loop* Why would I assume that? Instead create and post a valid [mcve] that we can copy-paste and demonstrates your issue. And please don't use the "go back" button of your browser to edit your question, it breaks the edits made by someone else. And format your code correctly

Comment: Ok i'm sorry. Thanks for the warnings.

Comment: *calculateAverage method is always gives the same output* Well, then post that code in a [mcve] form. Otherwise you'll get downvoted and your question closed. (Re)read [ask] section of the [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do but I'll make a guess and state that:

1. you don't need an Array to keep track of your buttons
2. you don't need to create a new ActionListener for every button
3. the ActionListener should be added to the button when you create the button

Instead you create a general ActionListener to be shared by all buttons and add the listener to the button when the button is created. You then add the buton to the panel at the same time so there is no need for the Array. The basic structure of the code can be something like:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();

        if (...)
            button.setVisible( false ); 
    }
};

for (...)
{
    JButton button = new JButton(...);
    button.addActionListener( al );
    panel.add( button );
}
```